# Angular 7 and up: service to inject two components not like singleton

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular and I have the same algorithm for many components but each of them to has to initialize the algorithm with different parameters. And these parameters changes during the executions and the components call the method of the service in order to do something with the last parameters.

For now my service is some like that:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class AlgorithmService
{
 
  private maxSizeCell:number = 1000;
 [...]
  constructor
  (
    private loginService: LoginService
  )
{}

setAlgorithmService([...]
{
}
 [...]
```

I cannot use a normal service because for Angular it is a singleton so I ask me if there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `providedIn: "root"` part, which makes the service singleton.

Then either add the service to your module's providers or in your component's providers.
I would recommend the component provider because it gets binded to your component's lifecycle and you can do any necessary cleanup on destroy.

I have prepared you a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tw9qxq?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html) to demonstrate how to add your service in to your component's providers.

Comment: I have to put my service in the `app.modul.ts` and declare it in the @NgModule
`({
  declarations:
 AppComponent,
      HomeComponent,
    [..]
` is it right?  In this files I have also  `imports`, `providers` and `bootstrap` vector

Comment: I updated my answer with a stackblitz demo, you can check it out.

Comment: I have understood very well, but I have to add in my code 
  `  providers:[
      DatePipe,
      AlgorithmService
    ],` in the `app.module.ts` file. I ask myself is it right? And why your code runs with this declaretion?

Comment: You do not need to add the service in your module's providers if you are going to use component level service injection. It is an either / or question. You can either add the service to your module's providers array or to the component's where you want to use the Algorithm service. If I am missing to answer something, please be more specific, thanks.

Comment: I have understood I have commited a mistake in my code I have not put  `providers` in my component. But is there a way to inject this service in anothter singleton service like you have done in your code without to add in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: That's not possible, at least not up to my knowledge since you can not declare providers for a service. However if you just want to execute some logic, you can have a file where you export functions which will execute some logic, think of it like a collection of functions, which you can use without the need of DI.

Comment: I start to understand but I have not idea to create this files (for the programming logic) inside Angular because I have always used the service for doing it. Have you a doc or an example?

Comment: Just create a .ts file, for example algorithmUtility.ts, include some logic functions and export them, then use them in your service/component, nothing extra needed.

Comment: I understand! is there some style guide to put these files? For instance I have:
`services` folder,  `models` folder and so on (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide).

Comment: I don't think this convention is documented in official docs but you can have a separate utility folder to store your so called functional services.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a single service which have multiple `Observables` like in the following example..

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})


export class AlgorithmService {

    private paramOne$ = new behaviorSubject<any>(null); // replace any with your parameter type
    paramOneListener$: Observable<any> = this.paramOne$.asObservable();
    paramOne(param: any) {
        this.paramOne$.next(param)
    }

    private paramTwo$ = new behaviorSubject<any>(null); // replace any with your parameter type
    paramTwoListener$: Observable<any> = this.paramTwo$.asObservable();
    paramTwo(param: any) {
        this.paramTwo$.next(param)
    }

    private paramThree$ ...

    }
}
```

now I can pass any parameter I want to any one of the Observables listeners and later call this parameters in any component in my project - you can do all that after you inject the service in any of your components `constructor`.

**component A** pass your parameters to your service

```
...

constructor(private algorithmService: AlgorithmService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

    this.AlgorithmService.paramOne(pass here your first parameter);
    this.AlgorithmService.paramTwo(pass here your second parameter);
}
```

**component B** use your parameters and dont forget to **UNSUBSCRIBE**

```
...
private readonly onDestroy = new Subject<void>(); // import subject from rxjs


constructor(private algorithmService: AlgorithmService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    
    // listen to your parameters
    this.AlgorithmService.paramOneListener$.pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy) // this will unsubscribe inside the component
        tap((paramOne: any) => { 
            
            // do what you want with your parameter

        }
    ).subscribe()
    

    ... paramTwo

}
```

you can also unsubscribe inside your html files using `async` pipe

good luck!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question? OP is clearly asking for having multiple service instances whereas your answer is the common convention of using reactive programming by sharing a single service instance over multiple components.

Comment: when someone is asking for help it's our duty to supply him with multiple solutions so he and other people can vote for the best answer..

Comment: Yes, of course, I'm with you on that but as I've mentioned in my initial comment, this is not a proper solution option, it is a different concept and doesn't solve the problem in any way therefore it is rather misleading.

Comment: I work with many angular developers, all of them are using `RxJS`, my solution is not a different concept but different approach.

Comment: I would kindly suggest you to re-read the question, you are clearly misinterpreting it if you think your answer provides a viable solution to the question.